# Is it feasible creating Continuity Care Document without using any api

Tags: java, jaxb, ccd, cda

I am currently working on creating Continuity Care Document (CCD document). Through my research i came to know about MDHT api [MDHT Developer Guide](http://www.cdatools.com/docs/developeruserguide/org.openhealthtools.mdht.cda.doc.developerguide/topics/topic_MDHTAPI.html)

Currently i have generated jaxb classes from CDA.xsd and i am trying to set values to jaxb object and marshall it to xml and its getting quite complicated. I am stuck in adding `patientrole>patient>given name` part. My question is am i doing wrong or is it extremely necessary to use API as the object generated is quite complicated. Someone who has worked in generating CCD document will understand.

Comment: How would you do it without an API? Is it feasible? I'm going to say *no*.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch. Yeah the task was getting complicated without an api.

Comment: Of course, that doesn't mean you can't write an API.

Comment: What is your specific problem in the Given name section? I've written code that generates a proper Patient Role without an API.

Comment: You may check "Unofficial CCD on Mirth Connect developer guide" eBook on how to built CCD without API. Available to download at - ccdonmirth.shamilpublishing.com